# How to share start location to destination route

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, dictionary, apple-maps

I am developing one application which has functionality like drawing route on map. User needs to start and stop button which indicates that user start drawing route on map with lat long. When user reached his destination and user stop it, I am able to see route from start location to destination location route and I want to share that route with someone through application.

Here is my basic idea of application so any one here please suggest me what to do for that kind of functionality.

Comment: It is one type of the navigation. I do same functionality but make a note it is not proper working in ipod so test it in iphone simply you need to add each and every location in nsmutablepath and then redraw a line based on that mutable path,. you get your desire result

Comment: Can you pls explain me or share with me your way what you have did it.

Comment: i posted my answer. have a look once

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, direction sharing is already possible when using Google Maps. As given in [Get directions and show routes](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144339?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en&oco=1), to send someone directions and a link to the route in Google Maps, follow the steps below:

1. Open the Google Maps app.
2. In the bottom right, tap **Directions** .
3. Select a route.
4. In the top right, tap More on three vertical dots.
5. Tap **Share directions**.

To help you on the implementation, you can use Maps SDK for iOS - [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) and [Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme) for a complete guide on how to work with or to launch Google Maps app for iOS and perform specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing that thing like this

```
-(void)drawSenderPath:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locPolyLine {
    [mapView clear]
    [pathSender addCoordinate:locPolyLine];

    GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:pathSender];
    // Add the polyline to the map.
    polyline.strokeColor = AppOrangeColor;
    if ([self.homeViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getPathColor)]) {
        polyline.strokeColor = [self.homeViewDelegate getPathColor];
    }
    polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0f;
    polyline.map = mapView;
}
```

Comment: How would you share with another user wich having same app

Comment: two ways to do it 1) Api calling 2) Socket programming

Comment: Ok so we can't do offline right.. Can plz suggest me how to get user current lat long get after every one minite

Comment: in location manager there is one method something like *allowdifferlocation*
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout: